# Can't open images downloaded through R

Tags: r

I have the following code in R

```
library(RCurl)
library(jpg)
library(imager)

url <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/San_Francisco_49ers_logo.svg/100px-San_Francisco_49ers_logo.svg.png"
filePath = "C:/Users/Path/To/File/Name.png"

download.file(url,destfile=filePath)

img<-load.image("C:/Users/Path/To/File/Name.png")
plot(img)
```

And I get the following error message

```
Error in read.bitmap(file) : 
  File f: C:/Users/Path/To/File/Name.png does not appear to be a PNG, BMP, JPEG, or TIFF
```

but when I read it in it says

```
trying URL 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/San_Francisco_49ers_logo.svg/100px-San_Francisco_49ers_logo.svg.png'
Content type 'image/png' length 6966 bytes
downloaded 6966 bytes
```

which suggests to me that it *is* a png file? I checked my file directory on my computer (Windows, if that matters) and the file does exist but cannot be opened by the windows photo viewer app because it says it does not support that file type. When I check the properties of the file its type is listed as png.

I am trying to download all 32 team logos this way and while I *could* just do it manually in less time than I have spent typing this question and trying to figure it out myself, the programmer inside of me refuses to quit!  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This image you download actually is a SVG.

Comment: Oh I meant to add that to the question. When I navigate to that URL myself and right click and select save as image if I change the suggested file name to `[name].svg` to `[name].png` then it works and I can open it as a `png` file in the windows app.

Comment: I guess there are two answers I'm looking for. The first being how can I download this properly, and the second being WHY does it work if I name it as a `.png` manually but not when I do it in R

Comment: How about `magick::image_read("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/San_Francisco_49ers_logo.svg/100px-San_Francisco_49ers_logo.svg.png")`? The resulting object is noted to be of format `png`.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you @IanCampbell! Do you (or anyone for that matter) know why it does not work the way I had it initially?